# Re-render the state based on same state change : Tic Tac Toe

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Doing TicTacToe game. I give a button a status `clickedX` or `clickedZero` once it's clicked. This changes the style of the button.

I want to change statuses of the winning line buttons which will change the styling again.
But once I click 3rd button in the line and change status to `clickedX` (hence 3 buttons with `clickedX`), I need to re-render again to set `newStatuses[i] = xWin`. Right now I have to make an extra click to re-render which is not what I want.
Tried usin `useEffect()` but that did not work out and docs says not to use `useEffect` in such scenarious. I also checked similar threads but could not apply responses to my case... :(

So how to change the button status to `xWin` right after the 3rd Button changes status to `clickedX`?

Code below:

```
function Board() {
    const [nextMoveX, setNextMoveX] = useState(true);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(Array(9).fill(empty))

    const newStatuses = status.slice();
    function handleClick(i) {
        if (nextMoveX) {
            newStatuses[i] = clickedX
        } else {
            newStatuses[i] = clickedZero
        }
        setStatus(newStatuses)
        setNextMoveX(!nextMoveX)
        handleWinning(status)
    }

    function handleWinning(status) {
        let scenarious = [
            [0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6],
            [1, 4, 7],
            [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8],
            [2, 4, 6]
        ]
        for (let item of scenarious) {
            const [A, B, C] = item
            function win(input) {
                for (let item of [A, B, C]) {
                    newStatuses[item] = input
                }
            }
            if (status[A] === clickedX && status[B] === status[A] && status[C] === status[A]) {
                win(xWin)
            } else if (status[A] === clickedZero && status[B] === status[A] && status[C] === status[A]) {
                win(zeroWin)
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Button classTitle={status[0]} onClick={() => handleClick(0)}/>
           .......
            <Button classTitle={status[8]} onClick={() => handleClick(8)}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Calls to setState are asynchronous ( [Doc](https://The%20calls%20to%20setState%20are%20asynchronous%20(%20https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value%20).) ).

```
function handleClick(i) {
    if (nextMoveX) {
        newStatuses[i] = clickedX
    } else {
        newStatuses[i] = clickedZero
    }
    setStatus(newStatuses)
    setNextMoveX(!nextMoveX)
    handleWinning(status)
}
```

Since setState is asynchronous, you are sending the previous value of **status** to your handleWinning function, not the new one.

Changing

```
handleWinning(status)
```

To

```
handleWinning(newStatuses)
```

Should work.

Another solution is to handle the winning state in a useEffect :

```
useEffect(() => {
 handleWinning(status);
}, [status]);
```

By using the **status** state as a dependency of your useEffect, you are guaranteed to have the latest value of **status**.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works with `handleWinning(newStatuses)`. Although regarding useEffect - is it a good practice to use these in such scenarious? React docs state that one should not use useEffect for [https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect] updating state based on props or states.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I gave the example of the useEffect because you mentioned it in your question. But as the documentation explains, there are many cases where a useEffect is not necessary. Your function determining who won could be called at each rerender and return the winner.


`// No need to pass status as parameter because the method will already have its last value
const xWin = handleWinning();`